# Overlay background not applying on quasar

Tags: css, vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm trying to put a div overlaying another with a shading white background. But Quasar won't apply the background color off the overlaying div, when color text css style is applied

```css
.overlayshadding {
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgb(255, 255, 246, 0) 30%, rgb(255, 255, 246));
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<template>
    <q-layout flat class="lightbackground flex column no-gutter items-center">
        <q-header elevated>
        <!-- ...........  -->
        </q-header>
        <q-page-container class="full-width">
            <div style="position: relative">
                <div style="position: absolute">
                    <!-- some card -->
                    <q-card></q-card>
                </div>
                <div class="overlayshadding">
                    Text to overlay
                </div>
            </div>
        </q-page-container>
    </q-layout>
</template>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code, and if you're unsure if the style is being applied, open the DOM inspector in your browser's dev tools.  I will point out that your first color is completely transparent, and your second color is almost completely white.  Under normal circumstances on a white page your linear-gradient is going to be **very** hard to see.  Why don't you test with other stronger colors to verify.

Comment: See this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/zYbXrRw).  The first div uses your exact linear-gradient background, the second uses the same except the second color is red instead of white.

Comment: Thanks for the codepen @yoduh, it seems that the q-card is somehow messing up the z-index, I found a work around for now